# JavaScript: JSON Loop Through Similar Key Names

Tags: javascript, json

Very new to programming and I'm doing some online tutorials. Hoping someone would be kind enough to help me.

What I have is the following JSON data from an API response. strOption[i] and strPrice[i] will go up to 10 even if there are no values so I want to get rid of those.

Formatting isn't perfect but I'm sure you get the picture.

```
cars {
     "car": [
         0 : {
           "carId": "17209",
           "strModel": "Discovery",
           "strYear": "2022",
           "strOption1": "S",
           "strOption2": "R-D S",
           "strOption3": "R-D HSE",
           "strOption4": "",
           "strPrice1": "68,600",
           "strPrice2": "71,100",
           "strPrice3": "85,400",
           "strPrice4": ""
         }
         1 : {
           "carId": "11349",
           "strModel": "Sport",
           "strYear": "2022",
           "strOption1": "SE",
           "strOption2": "HSE",
           "strOption3": "HST",
           "strOption4": "",
           "strPrice1": "82,200",
           "strPrice2": "93,700",
           "strPrice3": "98,100",
           "strPrice4": ""
         }
      ]
   }
```

What I want to do is loop through the data and end up with this.
*Note strOption1 must pair with strPrice1 so I can access strOptions[0] with strPrices[0], etc.

```
cars {
     "car": [
         0 : {
           "carId": "17209",
           "strModel": "Discovery",
           "strYear": "2022",
           "strOptions": ["S", "R-D S", "R-D HSE"],
           "strPrices": ["68,600", "71,100", "85,400"]
         }
         1 : {
           "carId": "11349",
           "strModel": "Sport",
           "strYear": "2022",
           "strOptions": ["SE", "HSE", "HST"],
           "strPrices": ["82,200", "93,700", "98,100"]
         }
      ]
   }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use combination of `Object.prototype.keys`, `Array.prototype.forEach()` and `String.prototype.startsWith()` to get the functionality you want.

```js
const cars = {
     "car": [
         {
           "carId": "17209",
           "strModel": "Discovery",
           "strYear": "2022",
           "strOption1": "S",
           "strOption2": "R-D S",
           "strOption3": "R-D HSE",
           "strOption4": "",
           "strPrice1": "68,600",
           "strPrice2": "71,100",
           "strPrice3": "85,400",
           "strPrice4": ""
         }, 
         {
           "carId": "11349",
           "strModel": "Sport",
           "strYear": "2022",
           "strOption1": "SE",
           "strOption2": "HSE",
           "strOption3": "HST",
           "strOption4": "",
           "strPrice1": "82,200",
           "strPrice2": "93,700",
           "strPrice3": "98,100",
           "strPrice4": ""
         }
      ]
   }
   
   const result = cars.car.map(el => {
       let details = { // default object
           "strOptions": [],
           "strPrices": []
       }
       Object.keys(el).forEach(key => {
          if(key.startsWith('strOption')){
              if(el[key]) // prevent ""
                  details.strOptions.push(el[key])
          } else if(key.startsWith('strPrice')) {
              if(el[key]) // prevent ""
                  details.strPrices.push(el[key])
          } else {
              details[key]=el[key]
          }
       })
       
       return details
   })
   
   console.log(result)
```

Comment: Let me kow in the comments if this is what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Thank you very much.  This seems to be exactly what I was trying to do.  I was looking at String Includes and the key values but I couldn't pull it together.

Comment: Let's see if I have this correct.
So the map method creates a new array (results) with the old array (cars.car). 
Not sure how to explain the "el".
You declare two new arrays of strOptions and strPrices to be added to the new result array.
You look at each of the key names and if it starts with (didn't know there was a startsWith) strOption, if it is not empty push to the array. Same with strPrice.
Else just add the old key and value to the new array.

Comment: Yes, you this is exactly how it works!